# Is Dio's The World actually allowing him to move at the speed of light?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

According to physics, stopping time would comes with a lot of hindrances such as:

- When stopping time, everything including molecules are stopped. You are stuck where you because you can't move air molecules out of the way. Also breathing would be literally impossible.
- With all molecules stopped, there would be no heat generated. Your environment would become zero degrees Kelvin (the temperature at which molecules stop moving) and you would freeze to death.
- Stopping time stops photons of light from moving, so you are unable to see

Also if Dio actually stopped time, how would this work if his stand only has a 10 meter radius? That means he's creating numerous time ripples because his time stop doesn't apply to anything beyond 10 meters.

**Would this mean that instead of stopping time, he is actually moving at the speed of light?** According to [one hypothetical question on the physics stack exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29082/would-time-freeze-if-you-could-travel-at-the-speed-of-light), moving at the speed of light would make time appear to stop.

Answer (score 0):

There's going to be some amount of magical hand waving in any time manipulation ability and I haven't seen Jojo or "the world", but perhaps it could be similar to a time stop from Artemis Fowl. A time stop is a finite zone in which time is stopped for the consciousness of all conscious beings inside.

To those who are inside, the only effect is that all communications and time-dependent devices (clocks, TV, phone signal, etc.) are stopped and living beings cannot fall asleep. Any natural processes happen normally, there's no wind but you can breathe but you cannot physically leave because the outside world doesn't exist in relation to a time stopped zone. When the time stop ends, those affected by it instantly have their time set to the normal time (e.g. if time is stopped at noon for 4 hours you experience noon for 4 hours and when it ends your time resumes normally from 4 pm).

To those who are outside the field, nothing appears wrong with the time stopped area and you can walk into it but any conscious beings who were inside are gone, trapped in past at the moment the time stop started and will only reappear when it ends.

The time stop apparently only traps your consciousness at that moment and detains the body of anyone affected until it ends, this is why I guess the whole molecules/photons not moving isn't a problem.

Comment: DIO's time stop is similar to this, except say time is stopped for 15 minutes and time was stopped at 9 am, time will resume at 9 am, not 9:15.

Comment: Time stop has never been stated to have a 'zone'.

Answer (score 0):

(Possible Spoilers For Parts 1, 3, and 5 of JoJo's Bizzare Adventure.)

Okay, now that I've gotten that out of the way, time stopping time.

> DIO (previously Dio Brando in part 1), acquired [The World] in his awakening. He then gets a random mansion and sits there and hires all these minions. Once the Stardust Crusaders get to DIO, DIO shows off his ability when Kakyoin does the 20 Meter Emerald Splash. DIO stops time and donuts (, which is a trademark punch named by fans,) Kakyoin. Once he has donuted Kakyoin, time begins and Kakyoin flies away. Joseph Joestar from part 2 says "He was suddenly blasted away! Impossible!"

Based off that information, I think DIO stops time, stopping everything in a certain radius, making everyone unconscious, but out of the radius they seem to be moving, explaining how us viewers are still able to see DIO

> , and Jotaro at some point,

move in Timestop.

> This also shows Diavolo's ability to time skip, where everyone does their actions unconsciously, while Diavolo is in conscious thinking.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It has never been stated that Time Stop has a radius.

Comment: Well, even if Timestop doesn't have a radius, it would make more sense as to the radius of Timestop would be in Dio's peripheral vision (the radius as what he can see) and some. This would make it so that if seen from farther away than the radius (for example, a camera) would see a complete SKIP in time, which would make more sense as to how people don't see Dio's (or Jotaro's/Pucci's/DIO's) actions in Timestop because, well, they can't see Dio at all.

Comment: ALSO, Dio's time stop ripples from outside of him and eventually returns back after Time resumes, so there LITERALLY has to be some sort of radius.

Comment: That's only in the anime

Comment: All because it's 'only in the anime' doesn't make it true.

Comment: are you agreeing with me? That time stop doesn't have radius?

Comment: Of course not. Did you read what I said?

Comment: And what says that the anime isn't canon? There have been multiple adaptations of manga-anime in which people agree the anime takes hold of the "canon wheel". I mean, everyone practically calls the Pillar-Men after their localized names and those names have practically been set in stone at this point, so what dictates that the anime or the manga is really what's true?

Comment: It doesn't matte, even if the anime was canon (which it is, unless not present in the manga as well) you're making that assumption based upon a little graphic animation, not anything stated. How do you know the ripple doesn't existent infinitely? The anime made a couple of mistakes, which are only present then. What people call a character doesn't affect the status of the anime.